# Find Number of answers

Tags: trigonometry

> Find number of solution of :
>   $$\sin x+\cos x =k\tan x \ \ \ \ :k \in \mathbb{R} , 0\leq x\leq2\pi$$

My work :

$$\sqrt{2}\sin (x+\pi/4)=\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}\tan x$$

now $\dfrac{k}{\sqrt{2}}=\tan y$ then :

$$\sin (x+\pi/4)=\tan y \tan x$$

now what do i do ?

Comment: @MathLover   $k$ is  a parameter . i want number of answers ($x$).

Comment: tangent is not defined at $x=\pi/2$

Comment: note that it is $\sin (x+\pi/4)=\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}\tan x$

Comment: You aren't supposed to find the solutions. Just the number of solutions?

Comment: @Fricul38 Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Consider the function

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\tan x}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin (\frac{\pi}{4}+x)}{\tan x}$$

and study the number of solution of

$$f(x)=k$$

Comment: Could not be easy!

Comment: @Fricul38 You are right it is not a great hint but I can't see any shortcut at the moment!